# Не работает python скраулер

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте, я сделал python скраулер, который должен скачивать изображения и 
все идет гладко до того момента, когда нужно поработать с URL изображения, великий 
питон мне выплевывает ошибку, что неправильный URL, но там написан полный бред,
т. к. URL правильный, помогите пожалуйста...
Вот код:

```
#! python3
# downloadXkcd.py - Downloads every single XKCD comic.

import requests, os, bs4
os.makedirs('xkcd', exist_ok=True)

one = 1
while one < 1900:
    url = "https://xkcd.com/" + str(one) + '/'
    one += 1
    print('Loading page %s' % (url))

    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    comicElem = soup.select('#comic img')
    if comicElem == []:
        print("Image no found...")
    else:
        comicUrl = comicElem[0].get('src')
        print("Loading page %s..." % comicUrl)
        res = requests.get(comicUrl)
        res.raise_for_status()

        imageFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()


print("Готово...")
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Automatic_py11.py", line 22, in <module> ress = requests.get(comicUrl)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 
'//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/barrel_cropped_(1).jpg': No schema supplied. 
Perhaps you meant http:////imgs.xkcd.com/comics/barrel_cropped_(1).jpg?
```

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: Мне не понятно как эта ошибка возникает и как ее исправить

Comment: `if comicUrl.startswith('//'): comicUrl = 'http:' + comicUrl` вроде бы из текста ошибки это должно быть очевидно

Comment: все равно не работает

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 0):

У вас ссылка начинается на `//` без указания протокола. Чтобы добавить протокол, можно `urljoin()` с базовым адресом использовать:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> urljoin('https://xkcd.com/path', '//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/barrel_cropped.jpg')
'https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/barrel_cropped.jpg'
```

Это также позволяет разрешить пути (без имени домена):

```
>>> urljoin('https://xkcd.com/path', '/favicon.ico')
'https://xkcd.com/favicon.ico'
```

В вашем случае это может выглядить как:

```
comic_url = urljoin(url, comic_elem[0]['src'])
```

чтобы из `comic_url` получить имя файла, [можно `url2filename()` функцию использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16501351/4279).